# Rename [hidden-text] to [hidden-content]

Tags: discussion, tags

Suggestion: Let's rename the tag [hidden-text](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-text) to [hidden-content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-content).

I don’t think there is a need to handle text differently from other forms of content (images, videos, …).

Example question (to which I added the tag, although the question is not about hiding text): [Because alt is not allowed on SVG image link, can I add a second display:none image to let Google see alt text?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113743/because-alt-is-not-allowed-on-svg-image-link-can-i-add-a-second-displaynone-im)

Comment: Maybe that is a bad example because it is about hidden alt **text**.   But I see you point, hidden content might be slightly wider and more useful in some cases.

Comment: Seems like a good change. Hidden content is a broad topic and text fits into that subject